# Shutdown of Executor service in Spring Boot when Tomcat shuts down

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, executorservice, shutdown

I have configured an executor service in Spring Boot as follows:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:executor.properties" })
public class ExecutorServiceConfig {

    @Value("${"executor.thread.count"}")
    private int executorThreadCount;

    @Bean("executorThreadPool")
    public ThreadPoolExecutor cachedThreadPool() {
        return new ThreadPoolExecutor(executorThreadCount, executorThreadCount, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    }
}
```

The app is deployed on a independent Tomcat instance. When the Tomcat server shuts down, I have found that there are still tasks in the queue that are not completed. As a result, I will lose data. Is there a way for me to call awaitTermination on this executor service so that it will get a chance to finish what is in the queue? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure there is -- but now what if the Tomcat server or Java application were to crash? If the information in the queues are important I would instead put effort into maintaining the queues' persistency (not a word ... but you know what I mean?) -- so that when the Java application boots back up it could populate the queue with the unfinished items. I know this doesn't answer your question at all - and I'm sorry about that! Good luck with your project, tho!

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. Your question is legit. These are tasks that I can afford to lose if -- God forbid -- there is a system crash. However, I would like to avoid data loss during a normal shutdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate with `@PreDestroy` annotation. Then perform the shutdown of the executo service from there.

```
@Configuration
class ExecutorServiceConfiguration {

    @Value("${"executor.thread.count"}")
    private int executorThreadCount;


     public static class MyExecutorService {
           private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

           public MyExecutorService(ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
               this.executor = executor;
           }
           @PreDestroy()
           public destroy() {
                  // destroy executor
           }
     }

    @Bean("executorThreadPool")
    public ThreadPoolExecutor cachedThreadPool() {
        return new ThreadPoolExecutor(executorThreadCount, executorThreadCount, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    }

    @Bean
    public MyExecutorService configureDestroyableBean(ThreadPoolExecutor cachedThreadPool) 
    {
      return new MyExecutorService(cachedThreadPool);
    }

}
```

Comment: I thought about this option. But how can I get a reference to the executor bean?

Comment: Updated the example. Of course you will use a wrapper class in real world.

Answer (score 2):

You can hook into the Tomcat Lifecycle by configuring your [`TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/tomcat/TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.html#addContextLifecycleListeners-org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener...-) bean.  It has a method addContextLifecycleListeners which allows you to instantiate your own LifecycleListener and handle any [Tomcat Lifecycle Events](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Lifecycle.html) as you want (such as, by calling `awaitTermination` on your `ExecutorService`).

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatConfiguration implements LifecycleListener {

    @Autowire("executorThreadPool")
    private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedTomcatFactory() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        factory.addContextLifecycleListeners(this);
        return factory;
    }

    @Override
    public void lifecycleEvent(LifeCycleEvent event) {
        //if check for correct event        
        executor.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @nicholas. This is taking it to a different level. I never thought about managing Tomcat programatically. Was hoping to add some code in a container shutdown hook. But I am working. I will definitely try your code. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to get it to work. Thanks @nicholas! I have learned something new today!